# Scrolling just one div with the main scroll bar

Tags: html, scrollbar

I've tried what seems like 100 different things and I've hunted all over this board and others so I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible. But here goes...

I am trying to make just one internal div on the whole page scroll, and it is now with a scrollbar on the div itself. But I want to make it scroll using the main browser scrollbar. This is the page: http://www.vqinteractive.net/temp/example.php  I want the div to scroll exactly as it does now, just using the main browser scrollbar.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

So, if the scroll bar is moved, you want only the specific div to move.
Try using the CSS `position:fixed` for all the other components except the one that will move.

```
<div style="position:fixed;">
    <!-- Header, will stay put -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- This one moves -->
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;">
    <!-- Footer, will stay put -->
</div>
```

I don't remember off the top of my head, but you may have to mess around with the CSS `top`, `left` to make it look right.